# How to avoid Case-Matching with Parsing?

Tags: arrays, string, haskell, game-development

I am working on a function which gets a String in FEN-Notation (known from Chess). An empty 3x3 board would be:

```
,,/,,/,,
```

on each cell, there can be multiple pieces stacked on top of each other, either white (w) or black (b). For example, a valid position would be:

```
bwb,,b/,,/w,w,w
```

I use the following data types:

```
data Player = Red | Blue deriving Show
data Cell = Stack [Player] | Empty deriving Show
type Board = [[Cell]]
```

I need to transform a FEN_String to a board. I thought about first splitting the original string into seperate lists on '/', but then I get stuck on how to process the resulting lists in the best way.

Is there anything better than case matching? I don‘t want to cover each possible case, I already did this once before for a different game like this:

```
buildBoard :: String -> Board
buildBoard [] = [[]]
buildBoard xs =   (chunksOf 9 ([Empty] ++ buildboardHelper xs))

buildboardHelper :: String -> [Cell]
buildboardHelper (a:b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == ',' && b == 'w') = buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest) 
      | (a == ',' && b == 'b') = buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == '/' && b == ',') = [Empty]  ++ buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == '/' && b == 'w') = buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == '/' && b == 'b') = buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == ',' && b == '/') = [Empty]  ++ buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == ',' && b == ',' && c == ',' && d ==',') = [Empty] ++ [Empty] ++ buildboardHelper (c:d:rest)
      | (a == ',' && b == ',') = [Empty] ++ buildboardHelper (b:c:d:rest)
      | (a == 'w' && isDigit b && isDigit c && isDigit d) = let number = (read ([b,c,d]) :: Int) in [Piece White number] ++ buildboardHelper (rest)
      | (a == 'w' && isDigit b && isDigit c) = let number = (read ([b,c]) :: Int) in [Piece White number] ++ buildboardHelper (d:rest)
      | (a == 'w' && isDigit b) = let number = (read ([b]) :: Int) in [Piece White number] ++ buildboardHelper (c:d:rest)
      | (a == 'b' && isDigit b && isDigit c && isDigit d) = let number = (read ([b,c,d]) :: Int) in [Piece Black number] ++ buildboardHelper (rest)
      | (a == 'b' && isDigit b && isDigit c) = let number = (read ([b,c]) :: Int) in [Piece Black number] ++ buildboardHelper (d:rest)
      | (a == 'b' && isDigit b) = let number = (read ([b]) :: Int) in [Piece Black number] ++ buildboardHelper (c:d:rest)
      | otherwise = [Empty]
buildboardHelper [',',',']  = [Empty] ++ [Empty]
buildboardHelper [','] = [Empty]
```

Comment: I would use a parser library like `parsec`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anything better than case matching? I don‘t want to cover each possible case, I already did this once before for a different game like this:

I would *strongly* advise to work with a parser library, not do the parsing manually. This will only make it worse. Parsing is often complicated when doing it manually: there are a lot of cases that need to be covered, and most manual parsers, don't allow to easily reuse the logic in another parser.

We can use [**`parsec`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) for example. This library essentially allows to combine very simple parsers into more complicated ones.

For example we can first make a parser for a single `Player` item:

```
import Text.Parsec(Stream, ParsecT)
import Text.Parsec.Char(oneOf)

_player :: Char -> Player
_player 'w' = Red
_player 'b' = Blue

player :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Player
player = _player <$> oneOf "wb"
```

now we can use the `player` parser for a `Cell`:

```
import Text.Parsec(many)

_cell :: [Player] -> Cell
_cell [] = Empty
_cell cs = Stack cs

cell :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Cell
cell = _cell <$> many player
```

and finally, we create a parser for the `Board` with:

```
import Text.Parsec(sepBy)
import Text.Parsec.Char(char)

board :: Stream s m Char => ParsecT s u m Board
board = sepBy (sepBy cell (char ',')) (char '/')
```

Now that we defined the parser, we can run the `board` parser with:

```
ghci> parse board "" "bwb,,b/,,/w,w,w"
Right [[Stack [Blue,Red,Blue],Empty,Stack [Blue]],[Empty,Empty,Empty],[Stack [Red],Stack [Red],Stack [Red]]]
```

It thus returns a `Right …` which means that the parsing was successful, and at first sight, it looks like it parses the stream correctly.

Probaably the nicest thing however is that we do not only got a parser for a `Board`, but for a `Cell` and `Player` as well, that we can use and combine indepdently.